# How do I set dynamic prefixes in Laravel routes

Tags: laravel-4, locale, laravel-routing

heres the situation - I'm building a site thats region based and I need to set it up so that the first segment of the route is a region i.e. of the type:

```
www.mysite.com/{region}
```

Currently I have routes set up like this:

```
www.mysite.com/businesses

www.mysite.com/businesses/show
```

I've tried a number of tricks but for some reason I can't get this to work:

```
www.mysite.com/{region}/businesses
```

in such a way that I need to filter by the {region} variable and that the {region} variable has to prepend every url in the site, also the {region} variable should also be accessible in the controller. I had a look at the localization options except I don't want to change languages here. I'm looking for implementing something of the following:

```
www.mysite.com/barcelona/businesses

www.mysite.com/new-york/businesses
```

I already have a table of all regions and slugs and the required relationships. Just trying to get this to work.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried (code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the region route on top of all other routes, I have similar feature for a project and that fixed it for me.

```
Route::get('{region?}/businesses', array(
   'as' => 'regionBusinesses',
   'uses' => 'RegionBusinessesController@getBusinesses'
))->where('region', '.*');
```

In your Controller

```
class RegionBusinessesController extends SomeController {

public function getBusinesses($region) {
    return View::make('YOUR_VIEW_NAME')->withBusinesses($this->YOUR_MODEL->FETCH_BUSINESSES_METHOD($region));
}
```